# Как сделать блоки без переноса

Tags: css

Есть код:

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 800px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как мне сделать при помощи CSS чтобы ширина блока .inner автоматически подстраивалась и чтобы блоки span шли одной линией? чтобы не приходилось ее выставлять вручную или при помощи js

Comment: вам надо чтобы блоки влезали все в `outer`? т.е. у `span` размер менялся или наоборот, требуется чтобы `span` одного размера фиксированного были?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш код:

```css
.inner {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

И уберите `width: 800px;`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```